# Unknown attack to SMTP server

Tags: smtp

From yesterday I have a problem with sending messages via my SMTP server (MS Windows Server 2012 R2, software: MailEnable 8.02 Professional).

I found that there are constantly sending some emails via SMTP server...

If I restart SMTP server, messages are sending after 36 minutes again.

Messages are sending from mailbox DEFAULT as user postmaster, so I've deleted this mailbox and user, but problem is persists...

Mail Relay is set only to "Allow relay for authenticated senders".

Can somebody help me, please?!

**Log from 2014/02/22:**

many logs like this:

IMAP LOGIN attempt failed from IP address. Client IP: ... Critical Mailbox: pwrchute

**Log - sending mails:**

```
02/22/14 15:41:36       ME-I0026: [008C17BF11314176A61944BC32586C19.MAI] Sending message
02/22/14 15:41:36       ME-IXXXX: [0059E32D89424F80825218C789108783.MAI] Remote server returned a response indicating a temporary failure. Server Response: (450 : Sender address rejected: DNS Timeout [02GHDNNJS300]**)
02/22/14 15:41:36       ME-E0034: [0059E32D89424F80825218C789108783.MAI] RCPT command to all recipients produced an error.
02/22/14 15:41:36       ME-IXXXX: [008C17BF11314176A61944BC32586C19.MAI] DNS resolved to the following record: IP Address=115.112.200.204, Family=2, Type=1, Protocol=6
02/22/14 15:41:36       ME-I0050: [0059E32D89424F80825218C789108783.MAI] Send attempt completed successfully, but some recipients did not resolve
02/22/14 15:41:36       ME-I0053: [0059E32D89424F80825218C789108783.MAI] Message generated a recipient failure message to sender.
02/22/14 15:41:36       [0059E32D89424F80825218C789108783.MAI] caused a Delay Message to be generated with a Message ID of [52228E1DC5634AE8BE72DA831F982FA7.MAI]. The recipient of the delay is: info@yonho.com
02/22/14 15:41:36       ME-I0054: [0059E32D89424F80825218C789108783.MAI] Message is being requeued to recipients where server returned an error.
02/22/14 15:41:37       ME-I0123: Domain [yahoo.com] has MX list [mta7.am0.yahoodns.net,mta6.am0.yahoodns.net,mta5.am0.yahoodns.net]
02/22/14 15:41:37       ME-I0026: [008CB29F18BE4B488BE7296579C09042.MAI] Sending message
02/22/14 15:41:37       ME-IXXXX: [008CB29F18BE4B488BE7296579C09042.MAI] DNS resolved to the following record: IP Address=98.136.216.26, Family=2, Type=1, Protocol=6
02/22/14 15:41:37       ME-E0038: [0058959360B44C7B97FBE0778E66271C.MAI] Communications Error: Socket connection to clavin.bcbsm.com failed (error 10060). The host was either not contactable or it rejected your connection. Socket Family = 2; Host=167.242.53.49; Port=25
02/22/14 15:41:37       ME-E0059: [0058959360B44C7B97FBE0778E66271C.MAI] Message Delivery Failure. Attempt (0): Could not connect to mail server for domain (bcbsm.com). The remote mail server could not be contacted at this time. Message has been requeued.
02/22/14 15:41:37       [0058959360B44C7B97FBE0778E66271C.MAI] caused a Delay Message to be generated with a Message ID of [489198ACB83F48588310940B5F65E54B.MAI]. The recipient of the delay is: info@yonho.com
02/22/14 15:41:37       ME-E0038: [007BF87508A44FF6937AC653D92C67D8.MAI] Communications Error: Socket connection to filter2.btcl.net.bd failed (error 10060). The host was either not contactable or it rejected your connection. Socket Family = 2; Host=203.112.194.38; Port=25
02/22/14 15:41:37       ME-I1350: [007BF87508A44FF6937AC653D92C67D8.MAI] Attempting to connect to MX 2 of 6 (filter1.btcl.net.bd).
02/22/14 15:41:37       ME-IXXXX: [007BF87508A44FF6937AC653D92C67D8.MAI] DNS resolved to the following record: IP Address=203.112.194.39, Family=2, Type=1, Protocol=6
02/22/14 15:41:38       ME-E0xxx: [008CB29F18BE4B488BE7296579C09042.MAI] MAIL FROM command returned with a 421 response. The message will be retried.
02/22/14 15:41:38       ME-I0009: [008CB29F18BE4B488BE7296579C09042.MAI] Remote server has closed connection after 0 milliseconds. Server Response: (-)
02/22/14 15:41:38       ME-E0059: [008CB29F18BE4B488BE7296579C09042.MAI] Message Delivery Failure. Attempt (1): Domain (yahoo.com) returned temporary error for email. Message has been requeued.
02/22/14 15:41:38       [008CB29F18BE4B488BE7296579C09042.MAI] caused a Delay Message to be generated with a Message ID of [9C01B03355704E2493D5E9BAC532DD91.MAI]. The recipient of the delay is: info@yonho.com
02/22/14 15:41:38       ME-I0123: Domain [rocketmail.com] has MX list [mta7.am0.yahoodns.net,mta5.am0.yahoodns.net,mta6.am0.yahoodns.net]
02/22/14 15:41:38       ME-I0026: [008CE54DA6994F9F82BE1C435EA16849.MAI] Sending message
02/22/14 15:41:38       ME-IXXXX: [008CE54DA6994F9F82BE1C435EA16849.MAI] DNS resolved to the following record: IP Address=98.136.216.26, Family=2, Type=1, Protocol=6
02/22/14 15:41:38       ME-I0123: Domain [b2bleader.com] has MX list [114.80.218.140,114.80.218.140]
02/22/14 15:41:38       ME-I0026: [008D31AA265A4E4DAE85DEB3E31B2316.MAI] Sending message
02/22/14 15:41:38       ME-IXXXX: [008D31AA265A4E4DAE85DEB3E31B2316.MAI] DNS resolved to the following record: IP Address=114.80.218.140, Family=2, Type=1, Protocol=0
02/22/14 15:41:39       ME-E0xxx: [008CE54DA6994F9F82BE1C435EA16849.MAI] MAIL FROM command returned with a 421 response. The message will be retried.
02/22/14 15:41:39       ME-I0009: [008CE54DA6994F9F82BE1C435EA16849.MAI] Remote server has closed connection after 0 milliseconds. Server Response: (-)
02/22/14 15:41:39       ME-E0059: [008CE54DA6994F9F82BE1C435EA16849.MAI] Message Delivery Failure. Attempt (1): Domain (rocketmail.com) returned temporary error for email. Message has been requeued.
02/22/14 15:41:39       [008CE54DA6994F9F82BE1C435EA16849.MAI] caused a Delay Message to be generated with a Message ID of [63B9797F84B34C609E84705EA7AA5FF8.MAI]. The recipient of the delay is: info@yonho.com
02/22/14 15:41:39       ME-I0123: Domain [yahoo.com] has MX list [mta6.am0.yahoodns.net,mta5.am0.yahoodns.net,mta7.am0.yahoodns.net]
02/22/14 15:41:39       ME-I0026: [008DC8DDDB8A41EFBD97AAF23BB3A7C4.MAI] Sending message
02/22/14 15:41:39       ME-IXXXX: [008DC8DDDB8A41EFBD97AAF23BB3A7C4.MAI] DNS resolved to the following record: IP Address=98.138.112.38, Family=2, Type=1, Protocol=6
02/22/14 15:41:39       ME-IXXXX: [007BF87508A44FF6937AC653D92C67D8.MAI] Remote server returned a response indicating a temporary failure. Server Response: (451 Blocked - see http://www.spamcop.net/bl.shtml?31.31.72.250**)
02/22/14 15:41:39       ME-IXXXX: [008C17BF11314176A61944BC32586C19.MAI] Remote server returned a response indicating a temporary failure. Server Response: (451 IP 31.31.72.250 is UCEPROTECT-Level 1 listed. See http://www.uceprotect.net/rblcheck.php?ipr=31.31.72.250**)
02/22/14 15:41:39       ME-E0034: [008C17BF11314176A61944BC32586C19.MAI] RCPT command to all recipients produced an error.
02/22/14 15:41:39       ME-I0050: [008C17BF11314176A61944BC32586C19.MAI] Send attempt completed successfully, but some recipients did not resolve
02/22/14 15:41:39       ME-I0053: [008C17BF11314176A61944BC32586C19.MAI] Message generated a recipient failure message to sender.
```

Comment: They could be coming from your machine if it is infected by malware; then it's not 'relaying'.

Comment: Some tip for (free) software I can use to find it?